# How merge two mp4 videos side by side with the help of FFMPEG and PHP code?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

Could anybody help me with the php code for FFMPEG to concatenate two mp4 videos and store the concatenated files as an mp4 at any folder in the server?
i find command for ffmpeg.but i don't know how to make it work in php..
ps: in the orther hand, is there any program like ffmpeg i can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) filter for side-by-side:

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex hstack /path/to/output.mp4
```

Using in PHP may look like:

```
<?php
    echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n";
    echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex hstack /path/to/output.mp4 >/dev/null 2> ffmpeg.log &");
    echo "Done.\n";
?>
```

Adapted from [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP).

Comment: echo shell_exec("ffmpeg.exe -i nameVideo1.webm -i nameVideo2.webm -filter_complex \"[0:v]scale=iw/2:ih/2,pad=2*iw:ih[left];[1:v]scale=iw/2:ih/2[right];[left][right]overlay=main_2/2:0[out]\" -map [out] -map 0:a -map 1:a -c:a pcm_s16le -b:v 768k videoFinal.webm");
i try to run your comand but it not works..there is no video output in my folder..i  tried above code.this is output but size is 0bytes

Comment: @student **Always make sure the `ffmpeg` command works before you attempt to script it.** If you ran the `ffmpeg` command in `cmd` first it will tell you, `Only VP8 or VP9 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM`, but you're attempting to use PCM audio which is not supported. Change `-c:a pcm_s16le` to `-c:a libopus`.

Comment: @student Also, I'm guessing that `main_2` is a typo for `main_w`, and unless you really do want two separate audio streams you're going to have to fix your `-map`s.

Comment: -  i think ffmpeg work because i try to run this code before and it works fine http://pastebin.com/whjWVZc0

Comment: @student That script is unrelated the issues you are experiencing here.

Comment: thanks you to much.i understand what did you mean..i will try to figure it out.